# How to configure REST without edit the controls manually?

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, configuration, rest-api, acl

Hello I am developing an extension for magento that adds a new call to the REST API. This call must be accessible to everyone so by now the guest user must be configured manually to allow him use this call.

I would like to automatically setup the permissions when my extension is loaded. Is there any parameter that I can add to the configuration files to do this?